# Local Linux path in html link

Tags: html, linux, path

I've got an internal webpage that ultimately displays a table of the lifecycle of a number of files.

I would like to add a link on the html page that simply creates an opportunity to copy the link and paste it into the terminal. I have /data/foldername, but every time I embed it in an a href tag it converts it to http://hostname/data/foldername.  I figured out that if I manually push file:///data/foldername, it will keep that (a few less letters to delete), but I would like to just be able to copy /data/foldername.  I understand that there are browser restrictions, and I am not hoping to left click and have it open automatically.  I would simply like to right click and copy, so I can paste it into the terminal.

Am I missing something, or is it just plain not allowed?

Here is a sample of my code, attaching it to an image and getting file:///data/foldername:

a href=file:///data/foldername img border="0" alt="Linux" src="redhat30x30.png" width="30" height="30" /a

If I do this (ideally what I would like to do) I get 
http://hostname/data/foldername

a href=/data/foldername img border="0" alt="Linux" src="redhat30x30.png" width="30" height="30" /a

My goal result would be to copy and be able to paste /data/foldername

I removed all the the greater than / less than signs because it was removing all of my text, but you can imagine where it would be.

Comment: A. we're guessing at this point as to what exactly is failing for you ;-) Update your Q with the smallest bit of `html` (That what's not working right?) that can demonstrate the problem.If you're using a fancy editor, that may be a feature. Did you creating your page in a non-html aware editor? B. Maybe also add a text "illustration" of what you require for output. C. Use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box to format highlighted text as code/data. Good luck.

Comment: I added some sample code... hopefully that makes it clearer.